# Cannot find module 'react' from '/react/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

Error: Cannot find module `react` from `/home/react/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components`

I am using cypress for unit testing of the components and when I am running the tests I am facing the above error and 'react' is already installed in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, it can't find modules, so you have to install them:
Make sure, `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-redux` are in your dependencies inside `package.json` file and then run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

for accessing `react` you need to import it like so :

```
import React from 'react';
//OR
import * as React from 'react';
```